# Aggregate function along other records

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate

Let's say I am going to fetch all records of table `T1`. Also, I need to have access to `min` and `max` date value of records.

I may do that using two queries:

```
select * from T1 ;
select min(created_at) as min_date,max(created_at) as max_date from T1;
```

This is two separate queries , but is it possible to have them in one query?
 I mean all records plus min and max value of a specific column.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *,
       (select min(created_at) from T1) as min_date,
       (select max(created_at) from T1) as max_date
from T1;
```

Comment: This is good for simple queries,but what to do when there is a complicated query containing `join`, `exists`. should i repeat all the job inside the sub query twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `T1` JOIN (SELECT MIN(`created_at`) AS min_date,
MAX(`created_at`) AS max_date FROM `T1` ) AS temp
```